# C++ debugger or unlinter for floating-point behaviour

Tags: gcc, floating-point, debugging

my program uses some floating-point arithmetics. On my own work station it does its job as expected, but on another machine it sports strange floating-point errors. Both machines employ gcc 4.4.3 on Linux and the compiler line for all objects is

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x -g -fkeep-inline-functions -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-type-limits -Wno-unused -Wno-reorder -Wno-vla
```

Is there a debugger or code checker ("unlinter") which specializes in detecting possible unintended floating-point behaviour during run-time or insecure floating point operations in the source? Of course, a set of options within the gcc would be of great benefit for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the version of `gcc` that you usually need to worry about. The floating point code is within `glibc` so you should check the versions for *that.*